# Theano used as default backend with Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, theano

I have just installed Tensorflow and Keras in a conda environment (with miniconda).

In the `keras.json` file, the backend is `tensorflow` and there is no environment variable `KERAS_BACKEND` defined, however, when I import `keras backend`, I am told that Theano is used !

I don't know what's wrong....

Comment: Could it be related [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43154999/567620)?

Comment: that's what I thought, but there is no `conda` folder in my `ENV/etc` directory

Comment: clearly, conda sets environment variables when I source the virtual environment, but I don't find where....

Comment: A workaround is to prevent the environement variable loading in the `__init__.py` file of `keras.backend` so that it uses only the `keras.json` config file

Comment: Is [this discussion](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6925) helpful?

Comment: thanks, but as said, I don't have any conda folder in my `etc` directory...

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions in fact:

1- When installing Keras with `conda install keras`, the solution I found is to overwrite the `__init.py__` file of the `keras.backend` module. In the file, I simply commented the portion of code where it checks for an environment variable. However, I have not found where the environment variable was set.

2- The proposed solution in other posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43154999/1141818) is the solution to find where the environment variable is set. For this, keras has to be installed with the channel of conda-forge `conda install -c conda-forge keras`.

Comment: As pointed out by keras developpers, installing Keras with conda is not the recommanded way, only pip is supported